# Creating notifications using SharePoint calendar 2010

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-foundation

Let me clarify my question.

I am setting up an electronic diary system. I want to create the notification in SharePoint using the the following criteria:

1. I want a generic mailbox to own the notification. If that cannot be done. Will I be able to change the owner at a later date?
2. Is there a way to set the notification to go directly to a generic email?

If I cannot do the above will it work in outlook 2010 or 2013